# Using redux state to redirect React router but connected props are empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

This is based almost entirely on the React-router basic auth example. The only difference is that the user data comes from redux with `mapStateToProps`. So why is the initial `this.props.isLoggedIn` simply empty?

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, userLoggedIn, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    userLoggedIn ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    console.log(this.props.isLoggedIn) // getting correct value
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          {this.props.isLoggedIn} // <============= EMPTY :(
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
            !this.props.isLoggedIn ? (
              <Redirect to="/login"/>
            ) : (
              <Redirect to="/studio"/>
            )
          )}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/studio"
            component={Studio}
            userLoggedIn={this.props.isLoggedIn}
          />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isLoggedIn: state.user.isLoggedIn,
})
```

Comment: is `isLoggedIn` a boolean?

Comment: @bennygenel yes

Comment: @bennygenel I see your point, when I do `toString` it shows, but the routing still doesn't work.

Comment: its not printing because of that try `{this.props.isLoggedIn ? 'loggedIn' : 'notLoggedIn'}`

Comment: can you try to log the value in render prop and see what it logs

Comment: another thing to try `<Route exact path="/" render={() => (<Redirect to={this.props.isLoggedIn : '/studio' : '/login'} />)} />`

Comment: @ilyo Probably the `this` in the Route's render method is not the same as the `this` in the App context. Try setting a `const { isLoggedIn } = this.props;` before the return statement in the App's render and use that value instead.

Comment: @Jaxx I made sure I pass the right object

Comment: @bennygenel `this` gives me the route object and not the component, so I have to pass it through another prop from the main component: `<PrivateRoute
            path="/studio"
            component={Studio}
            userLoggedIn={this.props.isLoggedIn}
          />`

Comment: @ajmajmajma can you elaborate please?

Comment: The render function gets passed it's own routeProps, (like render (routeProps) => {} ), and you also have to pass in your apps props

Comment: @ajmajmajma can you give an example? because this is what I thought I did by passing `userLoggedIn` through the `PrivateRoute`